Is there a limit to how complex a single ABAP statement should be?
I was looking at someone's code today and found this beast:
    et_sort_iterations = VALUE #( FOR lv_iteration = 0  THEN lv_iteration + 1 WHILE lv_break = 0
                       LET lt_sku = get_valid_sku( EXPORTING it_sku = et_sku iv_iteration = conv #( lv_iteration ) CHANGING cv_break = lv_break )
                           lv_count = 0
                       IN FOR GROUPS <ls_group> OF ls_temp IN lt_sku GROUP BY ( pdc = ls_temp-pdc werks = ls_temp-werks matnr = ls_temp-matnr )
                          LET lv_line = REDUCE gty_sku( INIT ls_sku TYPE gty_sku
                                                        FOR ls_row IN GROUP <ls_group>
                                                        NEXT ls_sku = calculate( EXPORTING iv_iteration     = lv_iteration
                                                                                           is_sku           = ls_row
                                                                                           iv_pdc_cutoff    = iv_pdc_cutoff
                                                                                 CHANGING  cv_count         = lv_count
                                                                                           cv_available_vol = cv_available_vol
                                                                                           ct_sku           = et_sku ) )
                                                        IN ( lv_line ) ).

It took me a while to work out what it's doing but that's probably mainly due to me not being familiar enough with the syntax. A big problem I have with it though is that you can't debug each part of the statement individually which makes it hard to maintain.
I was wondering what people's thoughts are on these kind of statements? Should we try to make as few statements as possible for efficiency or is there a limit to how complex an individual statement should be?

In general I am  not a big fan of comments, but this code definetly needs some explanation.

I prefer a balance between readability, maintain/debug and efficiency (not necessarily in that order). You must also take care of the version of SAP ABAP on the client.
Regarding efficiency, I think this type of coding contributes very little and is more prone to errors. It is one thing to do a SELECT * without WHERE when it is not necessary and another to replace one or more statements with a single inline expression...
So I don't prefer it. I only use it when I save declaring many auxiliary variables, when I save many lines of code or when there is no other alternative in the process logic

As it's opinion-based, I guess it's best to post the question to SAP forums or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Debug would be difficult, better names are to be used (to avoid comments), etc. Hopefully, there's an AUnit Test Method for that (can be also used as documentation), right? ;-)

I personally try to follow the principles that the community tries to recommend. For example, readability, extensibility, performance are all important factors that have strengthened me in practice.
Fortunately, there is more useful documentation available on the web. What I try to follow and adhere to the most is the CleanABAP rules.
Here is the link:
https://github.com/SAP/styleguides/blob/main/clean-abap/CleanABAP.md#clean-abap
In your example, there are some principles that run counter to CleanABAP. For example:

Do one thing, do it well, do it only
Optimize for reading, not for writing
Keep single parameter calls on one line
Line-break multiple parameters
Write testable code
Readability rules

But there are other useful guidelines as well.
DSAG recommendations:
https://www.dsag.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/dsag_recommendation_abap_development.pdf
ABAP-best-practice:
https://ilyakaznacheev.github.io/abap-best-practice/
